# NSOpenGLView: drawing from different thread, glitches / flickers when live resizing

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, opengl, nsopenglview

I'm new to macOS development.

Currently I'm implementing a `NSOpenGLView` with a third-party library.

- The `update` function is a callback from the library, which will be called when a new frame arrives. Since it's expected to return immediately, the drawing should be called asynchronously.
- I tried to use `DispatchQueue.main.async()` here, however I found that it would block the main thread, e.g. there will be no animation when the container window is being resized. So I created a dispatch queue for drawing.
- Now resizing is pretty smooth, however the view **glitches** seriously during resizing. I think the reason should be drawing from different thread (when resizing, the view is also redrawn from main thread), however I'm not sure the concrete reason.
- Glitches only happen while **window bound is changing**. During the resizing, if stop dragging for a while, no glitches observed.

**(Update: The problem only happens if double buffering is enabled)**

A demo screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

```swift
func update() {
  videoView.glQueue.async {
    videoView.drawRect()
  }
}

class VideoView: NSOpenGLView {

  lazy var glQueue: DispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "gl", attributes: .serial)

  override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    self.drawRect()
  }

  func drawRect() {
    openGLContext?.lock()
    openGLContext?.makeCurrentContext()
    doDrawing()
    openGLContext?.flushBuffer()
    openGLContext?.unlock()
  }
}
```

I tried for several solutions.

- Call `videoView.drawRect()` in main queue will totally block the resize.
- Add lock to `update()` or `draw()` will eliminate glitches, but the UI thread is still very slow with choppy resizing.

```swift
class VideoView: NSOpenGLView {
  override func update() {
    // lock with NSLock / lock the context
    super.update()
    // unlock
  }
}
```

- Check `window.inLiveResize`, and stop calling `videoView.drawRect()` if true. When resizing, the draw() function is called automatically. This approach works well with quite smooth resizing, however when pause dragging, the view will freeze since the LiveResize event is not finished.

```swift
func update() {
  if !(videoView.window!.inLiveResize) {
    videoView.glQueue.async {
      videoView.drawRect()
    }
  }
}
```

I finally managed to figure out a workaround, but it's still imperfect and I'm sure it's not the right direction.

Please suggest whether I'm doing this in the right way, or better solution / best practice about **drawing without blocking UI**. Thanks!

Comment: What flickers exactly, the entire view or what is within it - specifically does the view turn black during resize?

Comment: Follow-up question: what do you do, if anything, to avoid the possibility that you'll get a second (or a third, or a fourth) `update()` prior to completing the previous `videoView.drawRect()`, thereby creating a growing backlog? How long does it take you to draw a frame?

Comment: @l'L'l I uploaded a screenshot. It does not turn black.

Comment: @Tommy Actually nothing. I don't exactly know how to deal with the external callback.

Comment: I've experienced the same type of thing myself; I'm not sure if there's going to be a solution using `OpenGL` that will keep the buffer completely free of garbage (even as cool as your example image is) without either blocking the drawing during resizing or having some sort of undesired flicker.